# Application-identifier does not match - App ID XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to update an app on my iPad. From my usual pc it works, but if I use the same project and try to load it on the iPad from a **different pc**, Xcode gave me this error and force me to delete the old app and re-install it. 
I'm using the **same certificate** in both PCs. Also the bundle identifier it's the same (because the project doesn't change).

What can be the problem?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem lies with the keychain in the other pc. Remove your old certificates from keychain in pc and refresh it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think it you have also installed the developer certificates in keychain also?

You have to install the developer and distribution certificate export from your old system and install it to your new system keychain. So there might be solve the issue as well.

Because in previous I have same issue faced and I solved it by installing the developer certificates in key chain and also download new provisional profiles from apple developer account.(Delete first old all profiles)

**Follow the steps this works for me:**

1 Delete all provisional profiles.

2 Delete developer certificates from key chain.

3 Add new developer certificates to key chain.

4 Restart the XCode.

5 Download the new provisional profiles(Make sure provisional profiles must be active)

6 Delete the derived data and clean the project(Ctrl + k)

Comment: When you say "Delete all provisional profiles", do you mean from xCode, or from the Apple Developer website?